# Psql installation getting failed in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Tried several times installing `psql` in Ubuntu 14.04, but failed with this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-11 but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any third party repository configured? `postgresql-11` should not be in Ubuntu 14.04. Can you [edit] your question and paste the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`? Can you do `sudo apt-get -f install` and post the results, too?

Comment: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiv$ . this is how sources.list look like

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
result of apt-get -f install

Comment: Please don't paste into comments. [Edit] your questions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the broken packages using the synaptic package manager and retry it. Mostly once the broken packages are removed, It'll install